# Load Javascript on page inside Div using jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page that uses Google Maps Javascript API (extPage.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script>


function initialize() {

    var cord = new google.maps.LatLng(28.545078,-81.377196);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: cord,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="map-canvas"style="width:600px; height:500px"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

That page loads fine as is but I am trying to load into a div on another page. I am doing it like this (test.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#LoadBut").click(function() {

            $("#extDiv").load('extPage.php');

        });

    });


</script>

</head>


<body>

<input type="button" id="LoadBut" value="Load">

<div id="extDiv"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

When I run it just like this I get an error `ReferenceError: google is not defined`. I've tried moving the `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>` to the test.php page. The error message goes away but the map does not load.

I've never been to sure about the best way to handle Javascript on a page inside of a div like this.

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Elements like the head section is usually removed when using load(), as you can't really load the entire page, doctype, head and all, into another page. That would make the markup really invalid.

Comment: You might have a try putting the script tags in the body as suggested in [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/).
Additionally I think the main cause is that the window.load event is not being triggered when you use load, so the initialize function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your requirements, you can use the 
[Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index#quick_example), whcih does not require any JavaScript.

You just place an img tag with a reference to a static map url into your page with the appropriate parameters. For your example:

```
<div id="extDiv">
    <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=28.545078,-81.377196&zoom=15&size=600x500&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false" />
</div>
```

[image]

See the note at the top of the documentation to see if the inclusion of API keys are applicable to your project.